# Is it possible to install a D compiler on the apache webserver?

Tags: apache, d

I want to compile a listener which connects the apache webserver with an arduino chip. To compile this listener it requires to have a D compiler installed. It is possible to install D on an apache webserver, compile the program and then execute it?

Answer (score 1):

For what you want you need a module for the Apache Httpd that does something similar to what Martin Nowak's DREPL does (compile, link and execute the D source on the fly). I could be wrong, but this looks like a terrible idea for anything serious...

A much better (proven, rock solid) solution would be to use FastCGI, SCGI or even good, old CGI. There are implementations of all three in D on the Internet.

- One of the few CGI implementations: https://github.com/dlang-libs/arsd-clone/blob/master/cgi.d
- SCGI: http://code.dlang.org/packages/reserved or old https://github.com/adilbaig/SCGID

Adam Ruppe's `arsd.cgi` module implements support for all the mentioned protocols: https://github.com/adamdruppe/arsd/blob/master/cgi.d

Comment: note that my implementation (the first link) actually does all three cgi variants: classic, scgi, and fastcgi. and it includes its own http implementation too